# Does the Pico i.MX7D support CANbus?

Tags: can-bus, android-things

I have conflicting information.  [This PICO documentation](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/PICO-IMX7UL-USG.pdf) shows pins 16 & 18 and pins 38 & 40 (on 40 pin header) are Can Tx and Rx pins. However, the [android things pinout](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d-pico-io.html) shows pins 16 & 18 and pins 38 & 40 as GPIO pins.

Are the pins dual purpose? Has anyone created some CANbus communication code in Android Things? Thanks!

Comment: There's no higher-level API to do CAN communication

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can use external CAN controllers, for example, with SPI interface like [MCP2515](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21801d.pdf) or CAN<->RS232 converters like [that](http://www.can232.com/?page_id=14).